# jdom2 and reading xml string not file from URI

Tags: java, xml, jdom-2

How can I read a raw XML string into jdom2 for manipulation?  Everything I am finding on the web is to load a file from a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They also expose methods to load XML from a java.io.Reader, in which case you can create a StringReader from a String, like this:

```
StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(myXmlString);
```